# How to call security setup when message received using Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration

I currently am using Spring Integration to get messages off of a queue and send them to a service using a service activator.  My issue is that the service I am calling requires a security context to be in place for the current thread.  This can be setup by calling a no-argument method, handleAuthentication(), of another bean.  I am wondering what the best way is to call this whenever a new message is received, prior to calling the service activator service?  I was originally thinking I would chain together two service activators, with the first one calling handleAuthentication(), but this seems incorrect as handleAuthentication() does not require any information from the actual message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your assumption about the security handling is correct. It is really just a side-effect aspect which should not be tied with the business logic.

Therefore we should use something which allows us to follow with the same behavior in the program. It is called as an `Aspect` in the programming as well.

For this purpose Spring Integration suggests a hook like `MessageChannelInterceptor`, where you can implement your `handleAuthentication()`  exactly in the `preReceive()` callback, according to your explanation.

Another trick can be achieved with the `<request-handler-advice-chain>` and `MethodInterceptor` implementation which should populate the `SecurityContext` into the current thread just before target service invocation.

Comment: I'm hitting an issue with how preReceive and postReceive are working.  These methods are being called every time the channel is polled, regardless if there is a message or not.  Is there an approach where these would only be called if there actually is a message?  Otherwise, it will just constantly be calling handleAuthentication().

Comment: Oh, Right! How about to do the same in the `postReceive()` callback ?

Comment: `postReceive()` actually always gets called when polling too.  I verified this by looking in the `receive(long timeout)` method of `org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractPollableChannel`.  When there isn't a message, the callback just receives null back for the message.

Comment: True, but you can check in your implementation `if (message != null)` and only in this case perform your `handleAuthentication()`.